# in Python, how do I inspect the type/length of values returned by a function or method?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inspect

Let's say I have a class `Test` with an attribute `names` and a method `calculate`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, names=('square', 'cube')):
        self.names = names

    def calculate(self, x):
        return x**2, x**3
```

Is there an easy way to determine that the number of names passed is equal to the (variable) number of values returned by `calculate` without actually passing data through that method? Basically I just want to require that the class definition is consistent at implementation time.

Something like an additional line:

```
    # check that calculate output and names line up
    # help needed here
    assert len(self.names) == # length of output of self.calculate
```

Answer (score 0):

> the number of values returned by calculate *without actually passing data through that method*

Without calling `calculate()`, the only solution I can see is to simply know ahead of time that it returns exactly two values, and thus `assert len(self.names) == 2`.

If `calculate()` can return an arbitrary number of values, I don't see how you can avoid calling it.

Comment: hm, i was afraid that might be the case. i was hoping there might be some internals analogous to `transform.__code__.co_argcount` (for number of arguments) that gives the number of outputs